# Android : KeyListener of EditText not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to filter the input char of an EditText to allow only valid float value. (e.g. :"12,45", only one comma, ...).

For this, I use the [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html) (dont confuse with onKeyListener or textChangeListener. I want to *prevent* the user from entering invalid data).

On Android 2.3.6 and 3.2 the keyListener.filter() and keyListener.getAcceptedChars() are not called and I can introduce any char (not limited to .getAcceptedChars())

I found little documentations about keyListener. If you got a good example or doc, I'm very interested.

Any clue why this is not working ?

What did I do wrong ?

Activity Code sample:

```
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(...);

        setContentView(R.layout.editTextTest_lyt);

...

 mEditTextTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTest);

mEditTextTest.setKeyListener(new NumberCommaDecimalKeyListenerTest());

...}
```

Layout Code sample:

```
editTextTest_lyt.xml:
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTest"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
                android:ems="5"
                android:maxLength="9"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

KeyListener Code sample:

```
public class NumberCommaDecimalKeyListenerTest extends NumberKeyListener {

private static final char[] mAccepted = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', ',' };
    private static final boolean    mSign = true;
    private static final boolean    mDecimal = true;

    @Override

    protected char[] getAcceptedChars()
    {
      Log.e("LODA", "KeylistenerTest.getAcceptedChars()"); // DONT show up in logs 
        return mAccepted;
    }

    public NumberCommaDecimalKeyListenerTest()
    { super();
  Log.e("LODA", "CREATE KeylistenerTest"); // show up in logs 
    }

    @Override
    public int getInputType()
    {
    Log.e("LODA", "KeylistenerTest.getInputType()"); // show up in logs 
        int contentType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        if (mSign)
        {
            contentType |= InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED;
        }
        if (mDecimal)
        {
            contentType |= InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;
        }
        return contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
    Log.e("LODA", "enter KeylistenerTest.filter"); // DONT show up in logs 

        // My logic will go here...

        // if user pressed '.', is changed for ','
        source = source.toString().replace(".", ",");
        source = source.toString().replace("6", "9");

        CharSequence out = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);

        return out;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the Android docs they state in relation to `KeyListener` that:

> Note that for most cases this interface has been superceded by general
>   soft input methods as defined by InputMethod; it should only be used
>   for cases where an application has its own on-screen keypad and also
>   wants to process hard keyboard events to match it

And for the method `getInputType()`:

> If you return TYPE_NULL then no soft keyboard will provided. In other
>   words, you must be providing your own key pad for on-screen input and
>   the key listener will be used to handle input from a hard keyboard.
>
> If you return any other value, a soft input method will be created
>   when the user puts focus in the editor, which will provide a keypad
>   and also consume hard key events. **This means that the key listener
>   will generally not be used, instead the soft input method will take
>   care of managing key input as per the content type returned here.**

So because you return a content type the KeyListener is ignored. Looks like this isn't possible then or did you find a work around?

Perhaps you could create a custom [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) instead and then set this on the EditText using [EditText.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher textWatcher)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).?

Comment: looks like I miss understood the keyListener class. (BTW, what does mean "generally not used" ?!?). thanks for this insight.

Comment: I think it means that in most cases it will not be used, with the exception being when the return type of getInputType() is TYPE_NULL.

Comment: Could be. anyway the doc on this class is not very clear/complet. I will make some test soon.