# how to remove 2 or more character from edittext on one click on android keyboard remove text button

Tags: android, android-edittext, character

I want to remove 7 characters from edittext on one click of romve text listener in android please give reliable solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082750/android-keylistener-of-edittext-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You can handle backspace click events and remove the number of characters as required.  Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event) on how to handle backspace button events.

Answer (score 0):

check out [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), it have methods you want like `beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)`